# Change alignment of Textboxes based browser width with Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

In this code I am trying to change the alignment of the textbox when the browser window hits a certain thresh hold. All I really want to do is have all the text boxes and dropdowns align right.

I have tried adjusting the `paddingLeft` and `marginLeft` of the Textbox. 

I have tried adjusting the `paddingRight` and `marginRight` of the label.

I have tried `innerHtml = '&nbsp'`.

For shiz and gigs I tried `outerHtml = '&nbsp'`.

I tried `insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '&nbsp')` for the Textbox. Then I tried `insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '&nbsp')` for the label.

**HTML Below w/ Javascript inside Body trying to achieve the re-alignment of the textboxes.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onresize = PositionElements();

        function PositionElements() {

            if (document.readyState == 'interactive') {


                var inputAptNumber = document.getElementById('inputAptNumber');

                if (fieldsetElement.clientWidth == 380) {

                    aptElement.innerHTML = '<br />';        

                    /*fix the indentation of the screen*/
                    inputAptNumber.style.marginLeft = '20px';
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
    <h1>Survey</h1>

    <form id="personalInfoForm" runat="server" method="post">
        <div id="nameDiv">

            <!-- Personal Demographic Information -->
            <fieldset id="surveyMainFieldset">
               <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <label for="inputfirstName" id="labelFirstName">First Name: </label><input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="50" id="inputFirstName" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="First name" required="required" runat="server"/>
                    </span>

                    <span>
                        <label for="inputMiddleName" id="labelMiddleName">Middle Name: </label><input type="text" name="middleName" maxlength="50" id="inputMiddleName" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Middle name" runat="server"/>
                    </span>

                    <span>
                        <label for="inputLastName" id="labelLastName">Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="50" id="inputLastName" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Last name" required="required" runat="server"/>
                    </span>

               </div>

               <div id="localAddressDiv">
                   <span id="streetElement">
                       <label for="inputStreetAddress" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelStreetAddress">Street Address: </label><input type="text" name="streetAddress" maxlength="150" id="inputStreetAddress" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Street address" runat="server"/>
                   </span>

                   <span id="aptElement">
                       <label for="inputAptNumber" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelAptNumber">Apt.#: </label><input type="text" name="aptNumber" maxlength="5" id="inputApt" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Apt.#" runat="server"/>
                   </span>

                   <span id="cityElement">
                       <label for="inputCity" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelCity">City: </label><input type="text" name="city" maxlength="50" id="inputCity" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="City" runat="server"/>
                   </span>

                </div>

                <div id="stateAddressDiv">
                    <span id="stateElement">
                        <label for="StateDropdown" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelState">State: </label><select id="StateDropDown" name="stateSelection" runat="server" ></select>
                    </span>

                    <span>
                        <label for="inputZip" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelZip" >Zip code: </label><input type="text" name="zipNumber" maxlength="9" id="inputZip" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Zip code" runat="server"/>
                    </span>

                </div>
           </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

**CSS Below**

```
#personalInfoForm
{
width: auto;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
height: 494px;
}

#personalInfoInput
{
overflow:hidden;
}

#personalInfoForm span
{
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#personalInfoForm #inputStreetAddress
{
width: 150px;
}

#personalInfoForm #inputApt
{
width: 50px;
}

#ageDropDown #childDropDown
{
width: 250px;
}

#localAddressDiv #nameDiv #stateAddressDiv
{
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}

span
{
display:inline-block;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

*Clearly I don't see what the issue is. Any and all help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need Javascript here. [CSS @media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are meant for use cases like these.

```
@media (max-width: 380px) { /* apply the styles below for screen size up to 380px */
  #personalInfoForm span {
    display: block;
  }

  #personalInfoForm input, #personalInfoForm select {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

**Working snippet with media query set to 600px just for demo purpose:**

```css
#personalInfoForm {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 494px;
}

#personalInfoInput {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#personalInfoForm span {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#personalInfoForm #inputStreetAddress {
  width: 150px;
}

#personalInfoForm #inputApt {
  width: 50px;
}

#ageDropDown #childDropDown {
  width: 250px;
}

#localAddressDiv #nameDiv #stateAddressDiv {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #personalInfoForm span {
    display: block;
  }
  #personalInfoForm input,
  #personalInfoForm select {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Survey</h1>

<form id="personalInfoForm" runat="server" method="post">
  <div id="nameDiv">

    <!-- Personal Demographic Information -->
    <fieldset id="surveyMainFieldset">
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <div>
        <span>
          <label for="inputfirstName" id="labelFirstName">First Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="50" id="inputFirstName" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="First name" required="required" runat="server"/>
        </span>

        <span>
          <label for="inputMiddleName" id="labelMiddleName">Middle Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="middleName" maxlength="50" id="inputMiddleName" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Middle name" runat="server"/>
        </span>

        <span>
          <label for="inputLastName" id="labelLastName">Last Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="50" id="inputLastName" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Last name" required="required" runat="server"/>
        </span>

      </div>

      <div id="localAddressDiv">
        <span id="streetElement">
          <label for="inputStreetAddress" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelStreetAddress">Street Address: </label>
          <input type="text" name="streetAddress" maxlength="150" id="inputStreetAddress" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Street address" runat="server"/>
        </span>

        <span id="aptElement">
          <label for="inputAptNumber" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelAptNumber">Apt.#: </label>
          <input type="text" name="aptNumber" maxlength="5" id="inputApt" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Apt.#" runat="server"/>
        </span>

        <span id="cityElement">
          <label for="inputCity" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelCity">City: </label>
          <input type="text" name="city" maxlength="50" id="inputCity" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="City" runat="server"/>
        </span>

      </div>

      <div id="stateAddressDiv">
        <span id="stateElement">
          <label for="StateDropdown" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelState">State: </label>
          <select id="StateDropDown" name="stateSelection" runat="server" ></select>
        </span>

        <span>
          <label for="inputZip" class="personalFormLabel" id="labelZip" >Zip code: </label>
          <input type="text" name="zipNumber" maxlength="9" id="inputZip" class="personalInfoInput" placeholder="Zip code" runat="server"/>
        </span>

      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```